# SQL - node.js express - react load behavior

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am relatively new to programming and i have a general question about the relationship between the server and client sides of a react on any other js app.

I have a mysql db with a table that i expose as an api (every n seconds) with nodejs express running on aws instance. That api is pulled as json and displayed every n seconds by the react app.

In my head, the connection between sql and nodejs is separate from the connection between nodejs and react. I think of that the sql is only connected to one thing (node express server) and therefore is not under a heavy load ever. Then node express server exposes the sql table through a few queries as 3-4 jsons. And finally, lets say, a 100 people open my react app and pull those jsons. So the only loaded area of the server is the node express.

Im i correct? or do i completely misunderstand how this works?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or do i completely misunderstand how this works?

It works the way you are going to make it work, and it seems you are on a good way.

The technique you are describing is called "caching" or at least some kind of, and is a good way to take load of your database. Instead of piping every request to the express server into the database, you store the result of the first request into memory (e.g. an object) of your express server. The next request will get served directly from memory, without asking the database.

Apart from polling you could use other communication channels too, but the same techniques would apply to avoid hammering the database

- [Server Sent Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events)
- Websockets
- Streaming (HTTP request does not close immediately, but server continues to send data every n seconds)